# Is indexedDB supported by Safari 6.0?

Tags: indexeddb

Safari6.0 no IndexedDB?

My Safari version is 6.0.2 (7536.26.17) on mac

I use the Tutorials from MDN but it not works

that's the code:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
```

indexDB is undefined

Comment: The software: it no workey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) no Safari version has support for IndexedDB.

Even MDN states the same in their ["Browser compatibility"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB#Browser_compatibility) table.

---

To include the comment of @acarlon here as well:

It seems as of **version 7.1 Safari is supporting IndexedDB**.

Comment: So indexedDB is shit? i can't use it in my project, Even my project 's environment is HTML5

Comment: @willian绿茶 I rather blame Safari. There is support in FF, Chrome and even IE10. So there it is already pretty well supported.

Comment: Not official. But seems that Safari 7.1 Desktop will support IndexedDB. Most probably at some point during 2014 will be released with Mavericks 10.10 http://html5test.com/s/0033c01c6c2f5c0f.html

Comment: Well, time moves on and caniuse shows indexdb support in both desktop and iOS Safari. MDN remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [indexeddb shim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/). This allows you to use the indexeddb API in Safari, because safari supports WebSQL on which the shim is builded.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the IndexedDB polyfill from facebook.

https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill